# AJAX based contact form 7 event tracking for new Google analyics code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, ajaxform, contact-form-7, event-tracking

So, we have a couple of wordpress websites. For one of the them the analytics code is of an older version (gaq.push) format.

For this particular website, we have the tracking set up just fine and Google analytics goals are properly working. In the "additional setting" section of contact form 7 (via WP-Admin), we are using:

```
on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/rfp-form-thank-you']);
```

However, for the other one, the newer version shows up which is ga.js based and the format looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-4248211-9', 'www.website.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');*
</script>
```

Now, the issue is: we tried following the method as we did for the other one but that doesn't seem to work. It may be because the analytics code is different this time.

How can we set up proper form submission event capture so that goals can be fulfilled in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

The method used in the question is in fact a virtual pageview, not an event. The correct syntax is as follows for virtual pageviews under the new Universal Analytics library:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/enter-new-pageview-here');
```

For CF7, you'd use the above syntax and then enter "/enter-new-pageview-here" as a destination URL goal, which is what I believe the qustioner is trying to achieve.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is different (and your example is in fact analytics.js based, not ga.js):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)